# How to read a specific line of a .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Assume I have a .txt file as below:

```
2
3
jack
hello
46
87
928
morning
```

I saw `fgetl()` funtion to read data line-by-line. However, it is working in such way that, when it is called first time, it takes the first line and when it is called second time it takes the second line an it goes on like that.

However, what I want to do is, to read a specific line(which I can specify).

For example I want to read line 8 first then line 2 and line 5.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You could read each line then store them in a cell array. That way you can access each line quickly. EDIT: A quick search produced this answer https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119284-reading-lines-from-a-text-file-and-storing-them-into-an-array

Comment: You can specify the row you wish to read with the textscan command.
Please see a full answer here:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/306876-how-do-i-read-only-a-specific-line-while-reading-a-text-file-in-matlab

Comment: You can't. You can instead read the entire file and then return then to a main function in any order you want. But any file reader will go searching on a file in a single direction. Otherwise you can reopen it several times and read one line each time, but this is not the best way

Comment: To read the 8th file, internally the full file is read until the 7th line break is found. Reading the whole file and indexing what you need is usually faster, unless you have insufficient memory to hold everything at once.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to read a specific line:

```
filename = 'file.txt'; % define file name
n_line = 3; % define line to read
fid = fopen(filename); % open file
result = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'Headerlines', n_line-1, 'Delimiter' ,''); % read line
result = result{1}; % unbox from cell
fclose(fid); % close file
```

If you need to read several lines, you can use a loop as follows:

```
filename = 'file.txt'; % define file name
n_lines = [3 7 4]; % define lines to read
fid = fopen(filename); % open file
result = cell(1,numel(n_lines));
for n = 1:numel(n_lines)
    result(n) = textscan(fid, '%s', 1, 'Headerlines', n_lines(n)-1, 'Delimiter' ,'');
    frewind(fid) % set file position back to the start
end
result = [result{:}]; % unbox from cells
fclose(fid); % close file
```

Comment: A `frewind(fid)` might be useful, it moves the indicator back to the beginning

Comment: @Daniel Thanks! I hadn't thought of that. Edited

Answer (score 1):

A quick way is to use a regex search:

```matlab
fr = fileread('textfile.txt');
matches = regexp(fr, '[^\n]*', 'match'); % 'matches' will be a cell array.  regexp search for '[^\n]*' returns elements separated by newline characters.

% Lines 8, 2, and 5:
matches{8}
matches{2}
matches{5}
```